# How to append list to numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to append the coordinates of a pixel and its corresponding RGB values to numpy ndarray objects.

```
image_file = cv2.imread("Mona Lisa.jpg")

X_train = np.array([])
X_test = np.array([])
Y_train = np.array([])
Y_test = np.array([])

for i in xrange(image_file.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(image_file.shape[1]):
        prob = randint(0,9)
        if prob>0:
            np.insert(arr=X_train, values=[[i,j]], axis=0)
            np.insert(arr=Y_train,values=[image_file[i,j,:].astype('float32')/255], axis=0)
        else:
            np.insert(arr=X_test,values=[[i,j]], axis=0)
            np.insert(arr=Y_test,values=[image_file[i,j,:].astype('float32')/255], axis=0)
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MonaNet.py", line 24, in <module>
    np.insert(arr=X_test,values=[[i,j]], axis=0)
TypeError: insert() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

I was able to workaround by converting a normal list to numpy.array:

```
x1 = []
x2 = []
y1 = []
y2 = []

for i in xrange(image_file.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(image_file.shape[1]):
        prob = randint(0,9)
        if prob>0:
            # np.insert(X_train,[[i,j]], axis=0)
            # np.insert(Y_train,[image_file[i,j,:].astype('float32')/255], axis=0)

            x1.append([i,j])
            y1.append(image_file[i,j,:].astype('float32')/255)
        else:
            # np.insert(X_test,[[i,j]], axis=0)
            # np.insert(Y_test,[image_file[i,j,:].astype('float32')/255], axis=0)

            x2.append([i,j])
            y2.append(image_file[i,j,:].astype('float32')/255)


X_train = np.array(x1)
X_test = np.array(x2)
Y_train = np.array(y1)
Y_test = np.array(y2)
```

But I would like to know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For an incremental build like this stick with list append.  Don't try to imitate it with arrays.  Either that or insert values into a preallocated array with `result[i,j]=value` like expressions.  Forget `np.insert`.

Comment: `np.insert` is not a `list.insert` clone.  You need to specify the row or column index(es) where to do the insertion (that's the meaning of the error).  It does not insert one element into a 2d array; it inserts a whole row or column.  And it returns a new array.  It is not in-place.  It is too expensive of an operation for iterative use.

Comment: Thanks for the performance tip!